# How to change the tooltip 'Active Files' on the CMFCtabCtrl's TabbedDocumentsMenu?

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

We have two ways in which we scroll through the tabs in the CMFCTabCtrl, either using the two buttons to scroll the window tabs or an interface that displays a pop-up menu of tabbed windows. This option depends on the EnableTabDocumentsMenu method in the CMFCTabCtrl. Be defualt the tooltip option on this button(menu) is "Active Files".

Same tabbed control seems to be used in Visual Studio even and I see the same tooltip there?

Is there any way we can change this tooltip text?

Answer (score 0):

The tool tip is set to IDS_AFXBARRES_OPENED_DOCS ("Active Files") in afxtabctrl.cpp when you EnableTabDocumentsMenu. To change it try calling:

> ```
> m_btnScrollRight.SetToolTip(_T("My Customized ToolTip"));
> ```

Your main problem is that m_btnScrollRight is protected so you're probably best off inheriting from CMFCTabCtrl and doing it in your own class (after calling EnableTabDocumentsMenu).